# Fail2ban with lots of IPs in log

Tags: networking, server, ssh, fail2ban

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 20.04 to run a Counterstrike source server and I'm experiencing a weird kind of attack on ssh (brute force?) I setup fail2ban and on the first day of server online a lot of IPs are trying to access (every 2 minutes a different IP is reported), some of them are banned, but the interesting thing is that some IPs "know the max retry" of the fail2ban, when I set up the max retry to 5 some IPs try only 4 times and when I setup to 3 retries the IPs reported just try 2 times.

It looks like they can detect the maximum retry and stop it before they get banned.

What can I do to stop it? I don't want to change the ssh port because I'm worried about making a mistake and being unable to access the server anymore. I'm thinking to use a key-based authentication, but I need to learn how to do it first on Windows.

fail2ban log:

[image: fail2banlog]

Comment: If an IP is banned, it will no longer show on the log (because the ban is at the network level), until it is unbanned and tries again. So, it seems normal to me.

Comment: The ban itself is not the problem here, the question is about multiple IPs trying to login the server. I think someone has created a "bot" that can use multiple Ips to try to access the server

Comment: hi @rodrigtti I believe these botnet attacks seeking open ssh ports are common place. If you like to setup ssh key based login and disable password authentication, these tutorials have step by step instructions: `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04` | `https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04/`. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing you can do to stop it. You need your ISP to filter. otherwise the request will always arrive at your location and eat up resources (how little it may be for each request...it will add up)

Comment: Welcome to the internet! You can visualize it as an infinitely long queue of robots at your front door, each one stepping up in turn to check if it's locked, and plunder your house if it isn't.

Comment: Internet is a mysterious place! You can never know how you will be attacked. Probably the IPs you mentioned are related and know about what happens to each other. Another alternative to `fail2ban` would be to use https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sshguard

Comment: To check that fail2ban really bans the IPs, please use the commands `iptables -S | grep -i "f2b-.* REJECT"` and `ip6tables -S | grep -i "f2b-.* REJECT"`.